# R - facet_wrap: facets are not ordered correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I've seen all the answers to this question and I thought I had it covered, but something is not working out.  My data is over 1500 lines that look like this

[image]

and my code is

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- read.table("C:/Projects/....txt",
                  sep="\t", header=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(dat)
ggplot(df)+
  df$scenario_f = factor(df$scenario, levels=c('Baseline','10% Increase','20% Increase','30% Increase',
                                               '200-200-200','10% + 200-200-200','20% + 200-200-200',
                                               '30% + 200-200-200','100-200-200','10% + 100-200-200',
                                               '20% + 100-200-200','30% + 100-200-200'),ordered=TRUE)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=points),position="identity", colour="darkseagreen4",alpha=0.3, bins = 40) +
  facet_wrap(.~scenario_f)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =(seq(0,1200, by = 200)))  +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma)  +
  labs(x="Points",y="Number of Members")+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size="12"),axis.title.x = element_text(size="12"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=10),axis.text.y=element_text(size=10))
```

If I remove the statement

```
  df$scenario_f = factor(df$scenario, levels=c('Baseline','10% Increase','20% Increase','30% Increase',
                                               '200-200-200','10% + 200-200-200','20% + 200-200-200',
                                               '30% + 200-200-200','100-200-200','10% + 100-200-200',
                                               '20% + 100-200-200','30% + 100-200-200'),ordered=TRUE)+
```

My plot looks like this

[image]

But the ordering of the facets is not correct.  It should be as specified in the factor statement and I get the following incomprehensible error:

> Error in factor(df$scenario, levels = c("Baseline", "10% Increase", "20% Increase",  : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   Incompatible methods ("Ops.ordered", "+.gg") for "+"

Comment: You can't just add `df$scenario_f = ......` to a `ggplot` call. _Before_ `ggplot(....) + ....` change the factor levels. I.e. `df$scenario_f <- factor(df$scenario, levels= ......`.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I also had to edit the levels as I added extra space around the '+'.